# Adding A Background Image to a UITableViewSection

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have a UITableView with custom sections. All I need to as a background image/view to this section. I have tried to add an ImageView as a subview to the tableView using `tableView.rectForSection` method but the `UITableViewWrapper`is hiding my ImageView. Any thoughts?

Comment: could you share your code and the screen shot if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size will change, so in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

1. get `.rectForSection`
2. set the frame of your `UIImageView / UIView` to that rect
3. add that view as a subView of the tableview
4. send it to back

Make sure your `cell.backgroundColor` is set to clear.

That should do it.

Comment: You're a legend, sir. The only thing I would like to add, is to insert it as a subview at index 0 and make sure you only add the view once. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Just letting you know, won't work with iOS 10.0 if you're using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: @AshrafTawfeeq - do you mean it works with iOS 10.1 and later, but not with 10.0? Because it appears to be working fine for me on 10.2...

Comment: It works if your pushing a view controller but if you're setting navigationViewController's viewControllers won't work for some reason...

Comment: @AshrafTawfeeq - hmmm... take a look at this: https://github.com/DonMag/SWSimpleDynamicCells